# Postfix:mail-to-script messages contain extra id and from lines

Tags: postfix

I have Postfix (3.6.3) forward mail for a user to a script

```
maild: "| /usr/local/sbin/mailsave"
```

The messages have extra From and id lines which break Python's email.Parser

Can you prevent Postfix from adding these lines?

```
From weberjn@host.my.tld  Sun Nov 21 19:11:19 2021
Return-Path: <weberjn@host.my.tld>
X-Original-To: maild@my.virtual
Delivered-To: maild@host.my.tld
Received: by host.my.tld (Postfix, from userid 1001)
id D3DFD783; Sun, 21 Nov 2021 19:11:19 +0100 (CET)
To: maild@my.virtual
Subject: s1
Message-Id: <20211121181119.D3DFD783@host.my.tld>
Date: Sun, 21 Nov 2021 19:11:19 +0100 (CET)
From: Jürgen Weber <weberjn@host.my.tld>

body
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the mailsave script that had removed the blanks before the id line, so the mail parser failed.